# jQuery .attr() returns "undefined" for existing attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have been trying to access a custom attribute defined on a `svg:rect` DOM element using jQuery (v2.1.4). The exact element is below:

```
<rect id="lane2-diag_D" currentLane="2" class="draggableCircle" x="250" y="125" height="20" width="10" clr="Chartreuse" style="stroke: gray; stroke-width: 1px; fill: chartreuse;"></rect>
```

This element is cloned from another element and it's id is changed. I'm trying to access the attribute after adding it to an `svg` element on the page.

When I try to access the `currentLane` property using `$('#lane2-diag_D').attr('currentLane')` it returns `undefined`. If I try to access  it with the javascript approach `document.getElementById('lane2-diag_D').getAttribute('currentLane')` it returns the correct value.

For all other element attributes jQuery returns their correct values.

What am I missing in the jQuery syntax?

Comment: Seems silly to ask, but is the jQuery library included on the page?

Comment: Yes. I am using jQuery selectors elsewhere on my page too. If it weren't included I believe the browser would throw an `undefined method` or similar error when execution would be attempted for `.attr()`.

Comment: Tested with `jquery 2.1.4` and it's working fine!

Comment: what $('#lane2-diag_D') returns?

Comment: `$('#lane2-diag_D')` returns the entire DOM element just fine. I missed adding to the question that this element is a cloned element with it's id changed. See question edit.

Comment: @mybirthname, `.prop()` doesn't work. I tried that before I posted the question.

Comment: I tried cloning, changing the id, and appending the `<rect>` to another `<svg>` in the DOM before reading its attribute, but received no errors. Take a look at [this](http://jsbin.com/dagisozena/1/edit?html,js,console). Is there anything else you did not mention?

Comment: Is this on webkit. It may be lowercasing the attributes (a known bug). Try on Firefox or IE instead to see if that's the problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson I had noticed the lower casing in the node's attributes list through the element inspector on chrome. But further inside the attribute's data structure the `localName` and `name` properties reflect the correct case. I did try `.attr('currentlane')`, but that too returns `undefined`.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am getting `undefined` as the return value in Firefox too.

Comment: How are you cloning the element?

Comment: I guess it's some jQuery thing then. jQuery and SVG don't mix very well.

Comment: @RobertLongson, it seems like the camel casing was causing the issue. I changed the attribute name to _current\_lane_ and `.attr('current_lane')` works fine. Please expound your comment below and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I don't know that what I said makes an answer. Feel free to write up what you discovered yourself as your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your code inside ready function and it will work, check example below.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){
  alert($('#lane2-diag_D').attr('currentLane'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<rect id="lane2-diag_D" currentLane="2" class="draggableCircle" x="250" y="125" height="20" width="10" clr="Chartreuse" style="stroke: gray; stroke-width: 1px; fill: chartreuse;"></rect>
```

Comment: I can access all other attributes just fine from within my JS file. It's just this attribute which is causing the issue. I don't believe this is the answer to my problem.

Comment: It's not about what you believe but you should test the code to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I fell on this thread before debugging the jQuery code to understand why `$("item").attr("myVar")` was returning `undefined` whereas `$("item")[0].myVar` was returning the right value. So I'm back to share my answer on this issue.

- For jQuery<3.0, the library is always lower-casing the variable used in `attr`.
  So, if you try to access `currentLane`, then jQuery is trying for `currentlane`...

Source https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.2-stable/src/attributes/attr.js#L42

- For jQuery >= 3.x, it looks like that this behavior has changed, so it should work correctly with these versions:

Source https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/3.x-stable/src/attributes/attr.js#L45